# PHP script errors when running in Windows console, no errors in browsers or Linux console

Tags: php, unicode, windows-console

`error_reporting(E_ALL);`
`ini_set('display_errors', true);`
`ini_set('log_errors', true);`

When I run a script from a browser, everything goes as expected, no errors. Same when running it from a Linux console. BUT when I run the exact same script from the Windows command prompt, I get errors when trying to insert some records into database. The errors are about Unicode characters, apparently:

`Incorrect string value: \'\\xC5 ANA\' for column \'name\' at row 1`
The windows console outputs this: `IZP─ĆRDO┼ ANA`
but the actual text is: `IZPĀRDOŠANA`.

What could be causing this and how to fix it? How does the Windows command prompt affect the data that's being processed?

Comment: Can be the problem the font with which the windows console is displaying output. You can set windows console font to Lucida Console. That font should be able to handle wide/unicode characters.

Comment: I'm not asking about how it displays the characters...

Comment: Show the code you are using to insert and also the input art of your script.

Comment: are you seeing the errors in the server logs?

Comment: Of course I'm seeing them in the error logs. The code is not the problem, it's a simple PDO PreparedStatement executed with parameters. I'm only asking how could the Windows console affect the data if it is downloaded from another website, not taken from cmd args.

Answer (score 2):

Seems like your windows console isn't set to right code page..

If you do:

```
chcp
```

Do you see

```
Active code page: 775
```

?

Anyway, you can set the code page to UTF-8 with:

```
chcp 65001
```

Comment: Yes, it is 775. I changed it to 65001 and tried to run the script again, still the same invalid characters shown... I know the data is UTF-8 because it is parsed from XML and the parser screams immediately if non-UTF-8 content is found.

Comment: @jurchiks I see, you'll have to use some other work around then. chcp 65001 was the only hope here :P

Comment: BTW, is there any way to persist that code page? It changes back to 775 when I close the command prompt.

Comment: @jurchiks It's set depending on OS locale, 775 is for latvian, lithuanian and estonian. Probably somewhere in the control panel language settings... I can look it up. I have 850 for example.

Comment: @jurchiks hey, check this out http://superuser.com/a/269857 Make sure you read it carefully (including comments) so you don't brick your system or anything

Comment: @jurchiks here is example of working reg value, I get 65001 by default now: http://i.imgur.com/hH0MV.png

Comment: @jurchiks but the problem persists even with 65001 as default right?

Comment: Yes, the problem hasn't disappeared.

Comment: @jurchiks It works for me like this (The console output at middle is some weird bug, but the output from php was written correctly in utf-8 to a file) http://i.imgur.com/SotbA.png , don't know what to say :|

Comment: Me neither. But at least it's not critical to make it work, it would just be a bit more convenient to run it from the console.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/21143/discussion-between-jurchiks-and-esailija)